# Prove that $(x^a − 1, x^b − 1) = (x^d − 1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $(d)=(a,b)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, and suppose that $(a,b) = (d)$, with $d > 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that
$I:=(x^a − 1, x^b − 1) = (x^d − 1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I was thinking: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, we know $d=\gcd (a,b)$. S0 $d=ap+bq$ for some integers $p,q$. Hence $x^d-1=x^{ap}x^{bq}-1=x^{ab}x^{pq}-1$.

However, I don't think this is helpful. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use roots of unity.

Comment: Note this result is valid for polynomials over any field.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think about the Euclidean algorithm (the really slow way).  In particular:

- If $a>b$ then
  $$
  \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b).
  $$
  You continue this until $a-qb<b$ and then start subtracting $a-qb$ from $b$ (and so on).
- Similarly, $(x^a-1)-x^{a-b}(x^b-1)=x^{a-b}-1$.  Therefore,
  $$
  \gcd(x^a-1,x^b-1)=\gcd(x^{a-b}-1,x^b-1).
  $$
  By applying the same argument/reasoning as above, this continues until you reach the gcd.

You can set up a nice induction where you assume that the statement is true whenever $(k,l)<(n,m)$ (this means that either ($k<n$ and $l\leq m$) or $(k\leq n$ and $l<m$).  Then by the argument above (if $m>n$), 
$$
\gcd(x^m-1,x^n-1)=\gcd(x^{m-n}-1,x^n-1).
$$
By induction, equals $x^{\gcd(m-n,n)}-1=x^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$.